# add and print non-ASCII characters to a list-python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, utf-8

With the python I have learn, I have been trying to – when you type in a phrase – translate it into symbols. I tried the maketrans() function, but that didn't worked. Here's my code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

message = "ab"
output = []
broke = list(message)
limit = len(broke)

for i in range(limit):
    if broke[i] == "a":
        output.append("¬")
    if broke[i] == "b":
        output.append("∆")
```

If I execute `print output` I get: `['\xc2\xac']` instead of ¬. Is there any way I could get around this?

Comment: you should probably also tag [tag:python-2.7] since its wouldn't happen in python 3

Comment: there we go, python-2.7 is tagged :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3, printing lists doesn't use string escape while in Python 2 it does, so doing the same thing in python 3 will achieve the save result you wanted. To achieve the same result in Python 2, you will have to do:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

message = "ab"
output = []
broke = list(message)
limit = len(broke)

for i in range(limit):
    if broke[i] == "a":
        output.append("¬")
    if broke[i] == "b":
        output.append("∆")
msg = repr(output).decode('string-escape')
print msg
```

output will be:

```
['¬', '∆']
```

Answer (score 0):

`output` is a list of strings. Just print the individual strings:

```
for out in output:
    print out
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking why is it printing `['\xc2\xac', '\xe2\x88\x86']` and not `['¬', '∆']` like in Python 3.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, but OP says "... instead of ¬" so it sounds like just the string and not the list was wanted?

Comment: Guess we gotta wait for the OP to clarify things

Comment: @abccd Feel free to add another answer about the differences between Python 2 and 3 on this. Even if OP doesn't want that, someone else who sees this question might.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks