# python list() function changing into (I think) utf-8

Tags: python, unicode

As part of my python project, I need to read a text file encoded in utf-8 and split it into a list. But when I use a letter followed by an apostrophe, list() seems to output utf-8. Say take the text file called infile.txt, encoded in utf-8, with the contents:

```
i like pi'
```

and the code

```
intext = open("path/infile.txt").read() 
print intext 

outnum = list(intext)
print outnum
```

it prints out:

```
i like pi’
['i', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'p', 'i', '\xe2', '\x80', '\x99']
```

I am using Python 2.7.10 on OSX 10.11.6.

Thanks!

Comment: It may help to open the file in binary mode. The way to do that is `open(<filename>, "rb")`.

Comment: Any reason you are using python 2? Unicode support is much more robust in python 3.

Comment: Yes, because in Python 2 `str` is a sequence of *bytes*. since you read a `utf-8` encoded file, when you put the individual bytes into a list, that is what you get. What do you *want* to happen? Really, if you can, you should just use Python 3.

Comment: It's not "changing ASCII to utf-8", because the input was not ASCII. The input was already UTF-8. If you want to handle Unicode code points instead of UTF-8 bytes, you need to decode the input.

Comment: Python2 will default to using ASCII, that's why you see the "extra" bytes there in the end. Python3 will properly show '’' as the last string.

Comment: @SacasticSully, good thought, but it's still doing it.

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney. Python 3 works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add and print non-ASCII characters to a list-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893420/add-and-print-non-ascii-characters-to-a-list-python)

Comment: @abccd - that was a very convoluted way to avoid using unicode strings and/or `.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eyes deceive you.... well, your terminal deceives you, but close enough. I can reconstruct your string and print the apostrophe. But really that string contained utf-8 encoded bytes. Python printed the encoded string and my utf-8 terminal decoded it and displayed the unicode character. this is a quirk of python 2. Python 3 does a better job of keeping encoded strings and decoded strings separate.

```
>>> chars = ['i', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'p', 'i', '\xe2', '\x80', '\x99']
>>> 
>>> s1 = ''.join(chars)
>>> print s1
i like pi’
>>> print repr(s1)
'i like pi\xe2\x80\x99'
```

Since your file is utf-8 encoded you can use the `codecs` module to convert it to unicode.

```
intext = codecs.open("path/infile.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
```