# How does 'print' work when it process 'str' type?

Tags: python, string, unicode, printing, repr

```
>>> a = '\xba\xba'
>>> a.__str__()
'\xba\xba'
>>> a.__repr__()
"'\\xba\\xba'"
>>> print a
汉
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

As my understanding, when print process 'str' type variable, it will use **str** function. But the results of **str** and print is different. Why?

Comment: Turns out I answered this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858729/python-list-function-changing-into-i-think-utf-8/43858795#43858795 today. You are on a utf-8 terminal. When python sent those two bytes the terminal decoded them and selected a unicode glyph to display.

Comment: Function 'str' and 'print' can both display something in terminal. What's the difference between these 2 function?

Comment: When I do "a.__str__()" in terminal, what's happening?

Comment: In the python shell, whenever an operation returns any object except `None`, python prints the python representation (`repr`) of that object. If I enter `"hello"`, it echos `'hello'`. So, `a.__str__()` returns a string containing the utf-8 encoded bytes but then the shell takes the `repr` which encodes those bytes into a longer string - purposely making sure it can be printed on an ascii terminal - and shows them. If you `print` instead, the print function itself is sending the encoded characters - not an repr - and renders differently depending on what encoding your terminal accepts.

Comment: You can see the difference with `for c in a: print repr(c)` verses `for c in repr(a): print repr(c)`. The first is shorter because its the encoded bytes, the second is longer because they've been converted to an ascii representation.